# Create a mulitindex pandas data frame from a multiindex csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am trying to create a multi-index pandas data frame (ultimately a csv file) from an existing csv file. I am having a hard time iterating over data frame because it contains more than 2 dimensions. How do I accomplish this? The original csv file looks like the following:

```
"Products" "Technologies" Region1 Region2 Region3
Prod1       Tech1         16      0       12
Prod2       Tech2         0       12      22
Prod3       Tech3         22      0       36
```

And I am looking to create a csv file which looks like this:

```
"Technologies"  "Regions"   Prod1   Prod2   Prod3
Tech1           Region1     16      0       0
Tech1           Region2     0       0       0
Tech1           Region3     12      0       0
Tech2           Region1     0       0       0
Tech2           Region2     0       12      0
Tech2           Region3     0       22      0
Tech3           Region1     0       0       22
Tech3           Region2     0       0       0
Tech3           Region3     0       0       36
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stack` and `unstack` are helpful functions for reshaping data frame, the former transform the column index to row index and the latter does the opposite, also [check this tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMpiq.png):

```
# transform regions to a separate column
(df.set_index(["Products", "Technologies"]).stack()

# rename the Region column and remove the name for Products column as it will be unstacked
   .rename_axis(("", "Technologies", "Regions"))

# unstack the product column to headers and reset the index to be columns
   .unstack(level=0, fill_value=0).reset_index())
```

[image]